# Error converting byte array to string in test

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, arrays, type-conversion

I have the following test that I've been trying to get working

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    byte[] testArray = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };

    string number = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(testArray);

    Assert.That(number, Is.EqualTo("1001"));
}
```

I get the following error

```
String lengths are both 4. Strings differ at index 0.
Expected: "1001"
But was:  "\0\0"
```

This puzzles me because my production code that converts a byte array to a string uses the same method then I log out the string and it's what I would expect.

Should I be doing something to the byte array before doing the conversion in this case?

Thanks, Neil

Comment: Just try the reverse `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1001");`. You will get `49,48,48,49` :)

Comment: Have you tried to convert the string `1001` to bytes and inspect the result?

Comment: I want to upvote this solely because you are using TESTS!!!

Comment: Thanks guys, total face palm moment when it clicked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte 0 in ASCII is not "0" but some escape character.

This will probably fix your issue;

```
byte[] testArray = new byte[] { 49, 48, 48, 49 };
```

Comment: This might help.  http://www.asciitable.com/  Notice bytes 48 and 49 are the characters 0 and 1 respectively.  Whereas bytes 0 and 1 are null and (start of heading).

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you are treating each byte as an ASCII code, the ascii code of 0 should be 48...

I suspect you actually want (using Linq):

```
string number=string.Join('',testArray.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

or

```
string number=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(testArray.Select(x=>x+48).ToArray());
```